# how create a facebook login with ANEs in animate CC?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, air

I received a proposal from a client where I should create an app with facebook registration, so I started searching the web for all kinds of ANE or SWC that do this service, the problem is that the instructions given on how to configure these ANEs are very shallow (many sometimes I miss the tutorial because they seem to skip several parts or leave them incomplete), among which I tried to configure are: myflashlab-facebook-sdk, OverGenANE, freshplanet, marpies-air-facebook-api.

I tried some youtube videos showing facebook-open-graph-api among others, but all I get are piles of errors, I've configured hashkey and every side of the application on facebook Developer the problem is to understand how to configure the ANEs inside Animate CC (that even inserting APP_ID continues to generate errors), even the owner of marpies-air-facebook-api tried to help me with his ANE and I did not succeed, maybe my knowledge is still low for this.

I've rounded the whole web behind information and tutorials, here is my last attempt before giving up the construction of the app, if anyone knows some REALLY easy way to integrate some of these ANEs (or others), have step by step explaining in detail their configuration (where to create the ".fla "within the sample folders of these projects for example), please help me! Thank you very much in advance..

Comment: Are you having issues only with FB ANEs or commonly with any ANE?

Comment: only with FB ANEs :/ so I see they work fine, but I can not configure them